# Trying to pass a selector but on second pass the object is passed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a function to change the image every half second 10 iterations. On the last iteration the image src will be set to the actual value.  This works for the first loop but the first time the `setTimeout` fires it passes the **object** `mo456` instead of the ***string***. I am using Firebug and the console shows:

[image]

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function loopMoHolder(lmc,thisMoDivID){
    ++lmc;
    ffRan = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1));
    console.log(lmc);
    console.log(thisMoDivID);
    $('#'+thisMoDivID+' .moHolder .ffbg img').attr('src','/img/moMoniker/mo'+ffRan+'.png');

    if (lmc <= 10) {
        setTimeout("loopMoHolder("+lmc+","+thisMoDivID+")" , 500); }
    else {
        $('#'+thisMoDivID+' .moHolder .ffbg img').attr('src','/img/moMoniker/mo10.png');
    }
    }
</script>
```

this is the html

```
<div class="moHolder">
    <div id='mo456' class="moCol ffbg"><img src="/img/moMoniker/mo1.png"></div>
</div>
```

I am sure the problem is the setTimeout line but I am unsure how to correct it.

Comment: You want setInterval ... but, do you really want to make a request for a new img src every half-second? This could create a bad user-experience.

Comment: Where do you first call `loopMoHolder`?

Comment: Please DON'T use setTimeout and setInterval with a string parameter. Always pass a function. That's all I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use setTimeout with a string argument, especially if you are passing an object.
I took the liberality to rewrite some of your code.

```
function loopMoHolder(lmc, thisMoDivID){
    var ffRan   = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1),
        $el     = $('#' + thisMoDivID + ' .moHolder .ffbg img');

    $el.attr('src', '/img/moMoniker/mo' + ffRan + '.png');

    if (lmc <= 10) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            loopMoHolder(lmc + 1, thisMoDivID);
        }, 500);
    } else {
        $el.attr('src', '/img/moMoniker/mo10.png');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should not use a string as the argument to the executed function of `setInterval` .. it should be a function (anonymous or not).  In fact, this is the problem.  What you have done amounts to calling:

```
loopMoHolder(valueOfLmc, valueOfThisMoDivId)
```

...which interpolates to (apparently)

```
loopMoHolder(9, #[object HTMLDivElement])
```

...which is syntactically incorrect.

Instead you probably want to call

```
loopMoHolder(lmc, thisMoDivID)
```

...as the other two variables may not even exist or work properly and could even cause invalid syntax.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    loopMoHolder(lmc, thisMoDivID)
}, 5000);
```

It also sounds like `setInterval` may be more appropriate so that you don't have to make subsequent calls in the method itself.

Comment: i wish i could give a thousand upvotes just to the first sentence

Comment: +1 I wish everyone forgot that these functions could ever be called with a string parameter.

Answer (score 0):

```
var intervalId, intervalCount = 0,
    img = $('#mo456 .moHolder .ffbg img')[0],
    loopMoHolder = function(){
        var rand = parseInt(Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1));
        if (++intervalCount < 10) {
            img.src = '/img/moMoniker/mo'+ rand +'.png';
        } else {
            img.src = '/img/moMoniker/mo10.png';
            window.clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
     };

intervalId = window.setInterval(loopMoHolder, 500);
```